# How to Convert a apk(android application )into xap (windows phone aplication)

Tags: android, apk, xap

I have an aplication in .APK for Android but how I can convert .APK into a .XAP for Windows Mobile or do I have to develop the application again?

Answer (score 2):

How to convert an orange to a watermelon? You have to re-develop it.

Consider using PhoneGap-like framework to support multiple mobile phone platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to redevelop it because Android is Java and XAP is a different language all together

Answer (score 0):

How you convert apk into xap, both are different framework , windows phone support windows os and android phone support android os, so you can't convert, better you redevelop..